# Added meta-oe recipe failed

Tags: yocto

By following this link:

https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/3.0.2/brief-yoctoprojectqs/brief-yoctoprojectqs.html

I can build an yocto image and able to boot and login.

The problem is I want to add meta-oe recepie.

Here are my steps:

```
~/poky$git clone https://github.com/openembedded/meta-openembedded.git

~/poky$source oe-init-build-env

~/poky/build$bitbake-layers add-layer ../meta-openembedded/meta-oe

cd ..

~/poky/source oe-init-build-env

~/poky/build$bitbake core-image-minimal
```

When the output image comes out, boot, login, there is no any meta-oe package added into image, ex: no fio, no stresstestapp...etc.

## Here is the output:

Loaded 2348 entries from dependency cache.

NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies

Build Configuration:

BB_VERSION           = "1.44.0"

BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"

NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal"

TARGET_SYS           = "x86_64-poky-linux"

MACHINE              = "genericx86-64"

DISTRO               = "poky"

DISTRO_VERSION       = "3.0+snapshot-20200309"

TUNE_FEATURES        = "m64 core2"

TARGET_FPU           = ""

meta

meta-poky

meta-yocto-bsp       = "master:92e172b5b4de8927d36409386dfce0fc2718f5d1"

meta-intel           = "master:bba67420e6ae08e12d486247542a33de25d9ccff"

meta-oe

meta-webserver       = "master:90683147fa6840b16816a75154dba89725ddb0a3"

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) to any third party site.

Comment: updated, please review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

meta-oe is a layer not a recipe. Layers are just logical separators, they have no influence on what is built.

Packages are the products of recipes and they are added to the image with

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " {some recipe name}"
```